# Firebase REST Auth on Android returns 500

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication

Up until last week, the only resonable path available (for a lot of reasons) to use Firebase in a Xamarin.Android app required using [Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin).  However, this appears to have stopped working as well.

Specifically, I had been able to successfully make the following call in my Android and iOS apps and get successful responses:

```
var contentString = $"grant_type=refresh_token&code=string&refresh_token={auth.RefreshToken}";
var requestContent = new StringContent(contentString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key={0}", this.authConfig.ApiKey));
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, requestContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

As of yesterday, I started getting the following `responseData` from the above code:

**iOS:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from this ios client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url":     "https://console.developers.google.com/project/<my_apps_project_id>/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Android:**

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<my_apps_project_id>"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-    certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
 }
}
```

After some research, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-cloud-endpoints/I-u3sAUU3Ts/AjdAsWkjAwAJ) Google Cloud Endpoints Google Groups thread that said to be sure the following are in the http request's headers:

```
Header x-android-package
Label servicecontrol.googleapis.com/android_cert_fingerprint

Header x-android-cert 
Label servicecontrol.googleapis.com/android_package_name

Header x-ios-bundle-identifier
Label servicecontrol.googleapis.com/ios_bundle_id
```

I added `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier", <my_apps_bundle_id>);` to my code before the `client.PostAsync` and it works like a charm.

Moving on to Android, I added `"x-android-cert"` and `x-android-package` to the request headers:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-android-cert", <my_apps_SHA1>);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-android-package", <my_apps_package_id>);
```

prior to my `client.PostAsync` call.  However, now I get the following responseData:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

A moment of venting:  For me, this is almost the last straw when it comes to Firebase.  It has been over a month of overcoming one undocumented and half-baked API/SDK after another.  It seems as if NOTHING works as advertised (including - off topic - getting Firebase working with an Angular4 project).  Thank you for letting me share my frustration.  Had I known how painful this was going to be, I would have setup my own MBaaS.

Before I give up on Firebase, I wanted to ask for help with this issue.  Any insights and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:***
I get similar results with the following changes:

```
 var requestContent = new StringContent(postContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key={0}", this.authConfig.ApiKey));
```

Comment: Firebase Auth recently documented their REST API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/ It documents how to get a Firebase ID token and how to refresh that. Are you using that as a reference?

Comment: bojeil -  First, thank you for taking the time to comment.  Short answer: Yes, everything above (unless I made a mistake) is based upon the Firebase REST docs and was the first place I went back to when things stopped working as they had been.  I greatly appreciate anyone's insights - especially if I've made a mistake here.

Comment: Are you using an Android or iOS API key? You can just use the browser API key (make sure you have no restrictions on it). The reference link I posted should work with that. Run the cURL command from a command line first to make sure it works with your OAuth credential. I suspect the problems you are facing are API key related.

Comment: Again, thank you for being willing to spend some time walking through this with me.  For the iOS app, I am using the API key provided in ``` GoogleService-Info.plist``` (from the Firebase console).  Likewise, for Android, I am using the API key provided in ```google-services.json``` (from the Firebase console).  In both cases, I read those files and extract the API keys and other credentials (to make my code much more reusable).  Per your suggestion, I changed the "api_key"/"current_key" in "google-services-json" and it worked.

Comment: Cool, I am glad it worked.